# sqlite3 -- can't open database file

Tags: python, django, sqlite, heroku

For background, I'm trying to migrate my sqlite3 local db to a postgresql db on Heroku.

I have no problem accessing the db locally through my (Django) development server.  However, when I try to push the db to Heroku, it says it can't open the file.

```
heroku db:push sqlite://path/to/db --confirm my-app-name
```

I get the following message:

```
Loaded Taps v0.3.23
Warning: Data in the app 'my-app-name' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
Failed to connect to database:
      Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError -> SQLite3::CantOpenException: could not open database: unable to open database file
```

Most everything I've seen on Google relates to some bugs in earlier versions of Tap.  Otherwise, I'm not sure what I should do here.

I've tried following the advice of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713816/how-do-i-pull-heroku-data-into-a-local-sqlite3-database-running-into-problems) and others about permissions, but I have full read and write access to the file and containing folder.  I'm not too experienced with permissions -- do I need to switch ownership of the db to another user?

Answer (score 1):

If /path/to/database is an absolute path, you need to do:

```
heroku db:push sqlite:///path/to/db --confirm my-app-name
```

Note the third slash.  It could also be a permissions issue, in which case you want to either change the owner to the current user, or give at least read permission to the database (644).

Answer (score 0):

I would try to save the data from sqlite3 to a fixture via dumpdata and then, after switching to postgres, load it again via loaddata.

Comment: Love the idea but I get this: `Error: Unable to serialize database:`

Comment: At this point, use --traceback flag on dumpdata. It seems, a foreign key is not found.